# How to change Default Wordpress language?

Tags: wordpress

Hello guys I use a WordPress theme it's by default English I want to change it to French when I change it on Wp-Admin only admin interface is changed not the Website
I used some translation plugins like G translate and they give me a multi-language Website but I want the user to see my website in french by default Can anyone helps me please !!!!!

Comment: Did you clear your cache? 
Can you review the translated content inside your WP Dashboard?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean but there's no problem in my dashboard I can set it to whatever language I need but I want to change my default website language

Comment: Is there a setting in G Translate to set the default language? If you're using that plugin to provide the translations, maybe you should ask them on their support forum: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/gtranslate

Answer (score 0):

if your Dashboard is in French now but your Front end in English that means that your theme doesn't support Localization or it just doesn't have the files for your selected language.

You can try Loco translate (free plugin from WordPress plugins directory) to check if you can translate the theme output. Mind that Loco translate (and any other of that kind) will work only if your theme supports Localization.

I am not related in any way with Loco translate
https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/